# Adding functionality to Intl.NumberFormat

Tags: javascript, prototype, ecmascript-intl

I'm trying to add functionality to the [format function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/NumberFormat) but there is something wrong with my code:

```
Object.defineProperty(Intl.NumberFormat.prototype, "format", { value: function(){
     //your logic here
     let orig = Intl.NumberFormat.prototype
     console.log(orig);// does not remember the original proto
}, configurable: true } );
```

What am I missing?

Comment: What do you mean "original proto"? What are you expecting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You basically catch the property itself. You want to get the *original one* so before it is overriden, and you may store its subobject references too through copying them:

```
{
   let orig = Object.assign({}, Intl.NumberFormat.prototype);
   Object.defineProperty(Intl.NumberFormat.prototype, "format", { value: function(){
      //your logic here     
     console.log(orig);// does remember the original proto
   }, configurable: true } );
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, however it seems that the orig.format is being re-written to the new declaration

Comment: @roni gadot right in that case you need to keep a reference,ive edited